# Seleccionar dos columnas con mismo nombre de dos tablas diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql

Si tengo dos tablas que tienen una columna que se llama `direccion`, y quiero sacar solo una de ellas como lo hago?

> Tabla cliente: ID, direccion, nivel, correo, password, nombre
>
> Tabla empresa: EID, direccion, nombre

Lo que quiero hacer es:

```
SELECT ID, direccion, nivel FROM cliente, empresa WHERE ID = 1;
```

El resultado que me da es que la columna `direccion` es ambigua.

Comment: Por favor agrega más detalles a tu pregunta. Cuál es la consulta que estás utilizando?, cuál es el resultado que quieres obtener?

Comment: Tu código acutalmente está haciendo un producto cartesiano entre tus tablas, es eso lo que realmente quieres?

Comment: Aunque a primera vista, la respuesta obvia a la pregunta es que uses un alias, o que agregues el nombre completo de la tabla antes de la columna, esto ignora el hecho que pareces tener problemas muchos mas serios con tu consulta. Como bien comentó @Lamak, tu consulta, aunque la arregles resultaría en un producto cartesiano, lo que es muy improbable que sea lo que quieras. Además, observando la descripcción de tus tablas, no veo ningún campo que establezca una relación entre las 2 tablas, de modo que no veo qué estás tratando de lograr con el join.

Comment: @sstan Exacto, ese es mi punto. Creo que es importante primero entender correctamente el problema que está enfrentado el op antes de responder, para poder dar una solución más completa

Comment: @DavidIsla Recién van 45 minutos desde que la pregunta fue posteada. No es necesario presionar para aceptar respuestas

Comment: @David: jeje. Aunque la marque como resuelto, apuesto que al momento abre otra pregunta cuando se dé cuenta que los resultados de su consulta no tienen sentido.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta porque no está claro cuál es el objetivo que se desea, faltan más detalles en la pregunta, y una pregunta con un título así podría generar resultados de búsqueda incorrectos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Estableces un alias de las tablas, y obtienes el campo que desees de cada tabla:

```
SELECT a.dato, b.dato FROM tabla1 a, tabla2 b
```

Si deseas únicamente el valor del campo de la tabla1:

```
SELECT a.dato FROM tabla1 a, tabla2 b
```

o si deseas únicamente el valor del campo de la tabla2:

```
SELECT b.dato FROM tabla1 a, tabla2 b
```

---

Basándonos en tu pregunta, si desearas obtener el campo dirección únicamente de la tabla cliente sería :

```
SELECT ID, cliente.direccion, nivel FROM cliente, empresa WHERE ID = 1;
```

o de otra forma :

```
SELECT ID, a.direccion, nivel FROM cliente a, empresa b WHERE ID = 1;
```

Comment: No es necesario establecer un alias, puedes usar simplemente el nombre de la tabla original.

Comment: Por favor trata de usar joins explícitos en vez de los deprecados joins implícitos

Comment: Al usar alias, recomiendo colocarlos así: `SELECT tabla1.col1 FROM tabla AS [tabla1]`.

Comment: @Mauricio Normalmente uno de los objetivos de un alias es que el código sea más fácil de entender y más legible. Por qué usar un alias que sea aún más largo que el nombre de la tabla?

Comment: @Lamak tu lo dijiste: `el código sea más fácil de entender y más legible`. el alias no necesariamente debe ser mas largo que el nombre de la tabla; mi comentario era solo un ejemplo :) otro ejemplo puede ser: `SELECT tbl_1.col1 FROM tabla AS [tbl_1]`.

Comment: @Mauricio es por el uso de `AS`?, ok. De todas formas, la pregunta es sobre mysql, así que no se pueden usar paréntesis cuadrados para los alias, sino que backticks

Comment: @Mauricio ni siquiera necesitas usar el `AS` para asignar el alias a menos que uses los backticks. Bastaría con escribir el query como `SELECT id, c.direccion, nivel FROM cliente c, empresa e WHERE id = 1` (aunque esto es raro porque genera un cross join entre las tablas cliente y empresa).

Comment: Es una buena respuesta +1. Sin embargo, estoy de acuerdo con Lamak en que el autor debería aclarar la pregunta y qué es lo que está intentando hacer antes de que se le responda

Comment: Borraron mis comentarios, no se cual fue la razón, pero bueno la pregunta ha ido modificandose, pero bueno lo que se pedía era : "Seleccionar dos columnas con mismo nombre de dos tablas diferentes".

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que te refieres a hacer un select de ambas tablas pero solo mostrar el campo `direccion` de una de ellas. Usa alias y establece qué campo quieres mostrar

```
SELECT t1.direccion, t1.campo2, t2.campo3
FROM tabla1 t1, tabla2 t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.tabla1_id
```

Esto es un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que deseas hacer es lo siguiente,

```
SELECT ID, 
a.direccion AS cliente_direccion,
b.direccion AS empresa_direccion,
a.nombre AS cliente_nombre,
b.nombre AS empresa_nombre
FROM cliente AS a, empresa AS b 
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Comment: ¿Qué aporta de nuevo respecto a la respuesta más votada que se hizo antes?

Comment: Que de esta forma obtienes ambos datos, al hacer el llamado, digamos desde PHP, te devuelve ambos datos con diferente nombre, no solo uno, en caso de hacer mysqli_assoc

Comment: Pero es que sólo quiere una dirección, no sabemos cuál de las dos exactamente pero sólo quiere una.

Answer (score -1):

La forma de hacerlo es:

```
SELECT cliente.ID AS ID_Cliente, cliente.direccion AS Direccion_del_Cliente, empresa.direccion Direccion_de_la_Empresa, cliente.nivel AS Cliente_Nivel FROM cliente, empresa WHERE ID = 1 AND empresa.EID = 2
```

Los Alias NO SON necesarios, pero permiten identificar en las columnas de la consulta a qué tabla pertenece cada una, de lo contrario, te mostraría: "Dirección" y no sabrías a qué tabla se refiere.

Realicé la consulta sobre el ID del Cliente "Y" el EID de la empresa 2.
Si no colocas ningún EID de la empresa, te arrojará (de este modo) TODAS las direcciones de la tabla "empresa" mientras que te mostrará siempre un mismo registro de la tabla "cliente" (el número 1).

[image: Resultados de la sentencia mencionada:]

Comment: ¿Qué aporta de nuevo respecto a la respuesta más votada que se hizo antes?